# How to disply the calender before 3 months and after 3 months only from current date onwords using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, calendar

I want calendar like this when calendar shows it's show current date and i want able see only in that calendar before three months date and after three months date only.

i am getting current date  and i am selecting any date.

input type is date

```js
 $(document).ready(function()  {
        $( "#txtTrtDtPreAprvlSubn" ).datepicker({ 
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '-3M',
            maxDate: '+3M',
        });
    });
```

```html
<input type="Date" id="txtTrtDtPreAprvlSubn" placeholder="Treatment Date">
```

$(...).datepicker is not a function error is comming

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current Date, calculate the min date and Max date and set these options to date Picker.

Like Below:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
$("#from").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
var munimumDate = new Date(date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() - 3));
var maximumDate = new Date(date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 3));

    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
minDate : munimumDate,
maxDate :   maximumDate 

    });
});
```

Comment: Did u added JQuery library references in your html page ?

Comment: <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">